# What preprocessing should I do to a multiclass segmentation mask?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I am working on a segmentation problem. My masks are tensors with a shape of (4767, 192, 192, 1) --> (num_img, height, width, number of channels). Each mask contains 13 different pixel values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 255).

What preprocessing do I need to apply to this mask in order to train a UNET model to segment my images into these 13 classes?

I am using Keras. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the following pre-processing steps to mask images.

1. Convert your mask to one hot encoding as it converts class to binary as [0,0,0]for 0,[0,1,0] for 1, and [0,0,1] for 2, and so on...

> `one_hot_masks = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(masks, num_classes)`

2. Resize the mask to match the models's input
3. Normalize the mask

> `normalized_masks = resized_masks / 255.0`